# Is there a way to decide local interface/IP address to be used in python ldap client?

Tags: ldap, python-ldap

My Vm have multiple interfaces and I need to choose a particular interface to be used with python ldap client. But I didn't find any way on how to specify an interface for ldap client. Each time it picks up one interface.
I did search a lot but all I find is conn.set_options() but didn't find any option to specify local interface.

```
#!/bin/python
import ldap

def get_ldap_connection(url, local_address, local_port,
                           version, timeout):
    # How to use local_address and local_port ???                       
    conn = None
    conn = ldap.initialize(url)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT, timeout)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_TIMELIMIT, timeout)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, timeout)
    conn.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

    return conn

conn = get_ldap_connection("ldap://w.x.y.z:389", "a.b.c.d", 12389, 3.0, 1000)
```

I am stuck with python2 only

```
# python --version
Python 2.7.18rc1
```

Thank you in advance.
Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: The source address used for outgoing connections is typically handled by the kernel as part of the routing decision (because it wouldn't work if your application selected a specific address but the outgoing connection was routed out an interface for which that was an invalid address). The solution here is "configure your host routing table".

Comment: Thanks a lot @larsks. One follow up question is can modifying the routing table cause any issue with services using other interfaces ?

Comment: That depends entirely on the routes you create! Specific questions about route configuration would be appropriate at https://unix.stackexchange.com, or perhaps https://serverfault.com;.

Comment: Thanks @larsks. Appreciate your help.